# How to get font-size, written in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, font-size

How do I get the font-size written in CSS? It is returning the wrong values.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/e8WDk/)

HTML

```
<div id="test">TEXT</div>
<div id="test2">TEXT2</div>
```

CSS

```
#test{
    font-size: 38.5648887px;
}
#test2{
    font-size: 38.564px;
}
```

jQuery

```
var a = $("#test").css('font-size');
var b = $("#test2").css('font-size');
alert("test  = " + a + "\ntest2 = " + b); // test = 38.5667, test2 = 38.5667
```

Comment: Do you mean to get the font-size of the same element? You have `$("#test")` twice. I think you may need `$("#test2")` too.

Comment: thank you... I edited this mistake. But the output is still the same... I added jsFIddle example.

Comment: Why do you need such precise values returned?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you use a lot of decimal places. According to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#length-units) there is no requirement for the precision needed for a decimal place. Just that decimals are possible.

That being said, I think the decimal inaccuracy you maybe encountering is the browser limitation of the number of decimal places it will store. Especially when it comes to pixels since you really can't display half a pixel.

You're probably better off using `em` which will scale to the current inherited font size if you're looking for that type of precision.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, however, you really don't need any jquery.  Font-size can all be done using pure css.

For example:

```
#test {
  font: 38px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#test2 {
  font: 24px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="test">text</div>
<div id="test2">Text</div>
```

Does that answer your question?

EDIT:
Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8WDk/2/

Comment: this is jsFiddle example... try it - http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/e8WDk/

Comment: Convert your pixels into 'em' and that should do the trick!

Comment: But how t get font-size by jQuery in em ?

Comment: Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/e8WDk/2/  -- Your jquery should be correct, it's just a matter of applying the correct dimensions in your css (converting px's to em)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the problem here are the decimals in font-size definition value.
Here is the correct way to do it:

CSS

```
#test{
    font-size: 38px;
}
#test2{
    font-size: 38px;
}
```

If you want a more dynamic behavior for any device, you must use "em" to define values:

CSS

```
#test{
    font-size: 16em;
}
#test2{
    font-size: 15.5em;
}
```

This is Responsive Web Design in case you want to research more about it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I've seen most browsers only parse up to the thousandth decimal place, so if your font sizes are nearly identical in that regard, then the browsers are probably just doing some rounding to give you the same value.

I'm curious though, why would you want two font size declaration that are nearly identical and less than 1 pixel in difference? That sounds like your approach to the problem needs to be reconsidered and a better way may solve the issue you are looking at.